# Swing Application Analyzer

Tags: java, swing

I believe an application exists that lets you visually analyze your swing application, I've used it before but I can't remember the name.

From what I remember, you launch your app from within this analyzer and you can hover over any component and the analyzer will tell you the properties of the component, such as the type, name of the host component, registered event handlers etc.

Does such an application exist? Or have I dreamt it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are thinking of [Swing Explorer](https://swingexplorer.dev.java.net/).

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what do you mean by analyze, but [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) gives an IDE that is Swing friendly and is easy to develop with.